# How to access additional claims in the Firebase security Rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am using Firebase Custom Authentication system, for that while creating a JWTtoken, I am using a Firebase SDK with Node.JS as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_sdk).

Documentation mentions that we can add additional claims while creating token and access them in security rules. I am trying to do the same, but it's not working for me.

Additional claims added like this:

```
let additionalClaims = {
   premiumAccount: true,
   email: email,
   name: name,
   role: role
};
let JWTtoken = firebase.auth().createCustomToken(id, additionalClaims);
```

And the way I am accessing it in security rules is like:

```
".write" : "root.child('Security').child(auth.token.claims.role)"
```

Please suggest me the correct way to access additional claims in the Firebase security rules.

Comment: It's all in [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-custom)

Comment: I *knew* we'd added it somewhere, just couldn't remember where. Thanks André! (btw: did you notice that the new docs now show up first when you do Firebase-related searches in Google?)

Comment: You might want to add a snippet from those docs as an answer (with a backlink to the docs). Sometimes the SEO on Stack Overflow answers is better than for the docs themselves. :-)

Comment: Is there any way to access these claims from inside the app? I.e. are they revealed in the app in any way?